# double click в tk.Text во время нагрузки

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Имеется виджет `tk.Text` с объемным текстом, и список слов, к которым нужно применить теги, те выделять различными цветами.
Это делает `self.tag_add` в в `set_highlight`.
Но `self.tag_add` необходимо вызвать несколько десятков `милионов` раз, что занимает какоето время.

Все работает хорошо, но есть проблема.
Во время работы, нельзя сделать `double click` мышкой в tk.Text тексте. При этом, если написать както так
`self.after(1000, self.tag_add, tag, index_start, index_end)` появляется `double click`, но при этом время работы возрастает многократно.

как реализовать правильно?

```
class HighlightText(tk.Text):

    @move_to_thread
    def set_highlight(self) -> None:
        tegs_names = tuple((tag, name.lower(), len(name)) for tag, name, in self._get_highlight_tegs_names())

        # применить все теги для каждой линии
        for line_num, line in enumerate(self.get(1.0, tk.END).lower().split('\n'), start=1):
            for tag, name, len_name in tegs_names:
                index = -1
                while True:
                    index = line.find(name, index + 1)
                    if index == -1:
                        break
                    index_start = '{}.{}'.format(line_num, index)
                    index_end = '{}+{}c'.format(index_start, len_name)
                    self.tag_add(tag, index_start, index_end)
```

Comment: А что за текст, зачем столько выделения цветом?

Comment: текст скриптов LoadRunner, выделяю все знаки припинания, цифры, ключевые слова, чтобы остаток остался невыделенным

Comment: Можно попробовать делать add_tag только для отображаемых в данный момент строк, при прокрутке передобавлять тэги.

Comment: а ссылкой какойто не поделитесь, как определять что отображено в текущий момент?

Comment: Кстати, спасибо за ваш вопрос, я когда-то искал, как раскрасить текст в текстовом поле, но не нашел. Видимо плохо искал.

Comment: спасибо, полезно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавлять тэги не во весь текст, а только в видимую в данный момент часть (грубо говоря обрабатывать ~20 строк вместо ~20k строк).

Пример как получить видимую в данный момент часть текста можно посмотреть здесь: [Find Visible Region in a Text Widget](http://www.effbot.org/zone/tkinter-text-visible.htm). Но я бы делал обновление не по "таймеру" (через `after`), а через привязку своей функции к свойству `yscrollcommand` текстового поля. Модифицированный пример с обновлением при прокрутке:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL)
scrollbar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT)

text = Text(frame, bd=0)
text.pack()

for i in range(1, 1000):
    text.insert(END, "line %s\n" % i)

def scroll_handler(*argv):
    # Верхняя видимая строка
    top = text.index("@0,0")

    # Нижняя видимая строка
    bottom = text.index("@0,%d" % text.winfo_height())

    label.config(text="top:    %s\nbottom: %s" % (top, bottom))

    # Где-то здесь добавляем теги для видимого диапазона строк

    scrollbar.set(*argv)

text.config(yscrollcommand=scroll_handler)
scrollbar.config(command=text.yview)

frame.pack()

label = Label(root)
label.pack()

mainloop()
```

Результат может показывать дробный, поэтому диапазон строк нужно округлять (начало в меньшую сторону, конец в большую сторону).

Comment: спасибо, то что надо